# Eigenvector equation manipulation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following equation $Ax=\lambda x$ where A is a matrix and $\lambda$ a scalar and $x$ a vector.

Then the following should be legal:

$\frac{1}{\lambda}Ax=x$
$\iff \frac{1}{\lambda}Ax-x=0$
$\iff (\frac{1}{\lambda}A-I)x=0$

And yet I think this is illegal, because

$Ax-\lambda x=0 \iff (A-\lambda I)x = 0$

Where am I going wrong?

Update: How can I show the two equations are equal?

Comment: Please edit to include in your post, the source of the exercise.

Comment: If $\lambda \neq 0$ there's no contradiction here... $\ker A - \lambda I = \ker \frac{1}{\lambda} A - I$

Comment: Where is the illegal thing? I do not see anything wrong.

Comment: How can I show that ker−=ker1−?